# JUnit on JavaFX, can't run test (IllegalStateException)

Tags: testing, javafx, junit

i'm trying to test some methods i have in my JavaFX project.

Previously, i could not run my test because of this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
```

Then, i looked here on STO, and added this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.saxsys</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfx-testrunner</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

After that, i added before my class the following tag:

```
@RunWith(JfxRunner.class)
```

So, the error changed to this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = main
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: [jfx-testrunner](https://github.com/sialcasa/jfx-testrunner) looks like a dead project to me. It hasn't been updated in 8 years and the instructions note: "Testrunner is going to be merged to mvvmfx ### 1.2 is the last version of testrunner". Maybe use something better maintained and documented, like [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX).  Or, if you want to stick with a similar framework, [the mvvmfx-testing-utils](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/tree/develop/mvvmfx-testing-utils)

Answer (score -2):

Well, I found it myself just a moment after I posted the question.

The solution was adding this:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
```

Before my test. Hope it can help someone else too!

Comment: But why don't you do it the way it says in the [documentation](https://github.com/sialcasa/jfx-testrunner)? Annotate the method `@Test @TestInJfxThread`.